# Creating a banking API and have customer have an address. How would I do that?

Tags: java

```java
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String street_number;
    private String street_name;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;

    public Address() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStreet_number() {
        return street_number;
    }

    public void setStreet_number(String street_number) {
        this.street_number = street_number;
    }

    public String getStreet_name() {
        return street_name;
    }

    public void setStreet_name(String street_name) {
        this.street_name = street_name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.bankingapplicationmain.bankingapplicationmain.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String first_Name;
    private String last_Name;
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Address> addresses;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirst_Name() {
        return first_Name;
    }

    public void setFirst_Name(String first_Name) {
        this.first_Name = first_Name;
    }

    public String getLast_Name() {
        return last_Name;
    }

    public void setLast_Name(String last_Name) {
        this.last_Name = last_Name;
    }
}
```

So far, I tried to use "many-to-one", "many-to-many", but I guess I am still not sure how these work! My create, delete, methods are working fine, but all customers are missing addresses when I try to fetch them.

What I posted:

```json
{
"id": 1,
"first_name": "Leon",
"last_name": "Hunter",
"address": {
"street_number": "902",
"street_name": "Walker Road",
"city": "Clearfield",
"state": "Pennsylvania",
"zip": "16830"
}
}
```

VS What I am getting:

```json
{
"id": 1,
"first_name": "Leon",
"last_name": "Hunter"
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Edit:

```java
import com.bankingapplicationmain.bankingapplicationmain.models.Customer;
import com.bankingapplicationmain.bankingapplicationmain.services.CustomerService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerService customerService;

    //get all customers
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> getAllCustomers(){
        return customerService.getAllCustomers();
    }

    //get customer by id
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> getCustomerById(@PathVariable Long id){
        return customerService.getCustomerById(id);
    }

    //create customer
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> createCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody Customer customer) {
        return customerService.createCustomer(customer);
    }

    //edit customer
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateCustomer(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid @RequestBody Customer customer){
        return customerService.updateCustomer(customer, id);
    }

}
```

```java
package com.bankingapplicationmain.bankingapplicationmain.services;

import com.bankingapplicationmain.bankingapplicationmain.exceptions.CustomerNotFoundException;
import com.bankingapplicationmain.bankingapplicationmain.models.Customer;
import com.bankingapplicationmain.bankingapplicationmain.repositories.CustomerRepository;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class CustomerService {
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerService.class);


    @Autowired
    public CustomerService(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }
    protected void verifyCustomer(Long customerId) throws CustomerNotFoundException {
        Optional<Customer> customer = customerRepository.findById(customerId);
        if(customer.isEmpty()) {
            throw new CustomerNotFoundException("Customer with id " + customerId + " not found");
        }
    }

    // Get all customers
    public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> getAllCustomers() {
        logger.info("Customer(s) found.");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(customerRepository.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    //get customer by id
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> getCustomerById(Long customerId) {
        if (customerRepository.findById(customerId).isPresent()) {
            logger.info("Customer found.");
            customerRepository.findById(customerId);
        }
        throw new CustomerNotFoundException("Customer with id " + customerId + " not found");
    }

    public ResponseEntity<?> createCustomer(Customer customer){
        logger.info("Customer created.");

        customerRepository.save(customer);

        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        URI newCustomerUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                .fromCurrentRequest()
                .path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(customer.getId())
                .toUri();
        responseHeaders.setLocation(newCustomerUri);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    public ResponseEntity<?> updateCustomer(Customer customer, Long customerId) {
        verifyCustomer(customerId);
        logger.info("Customer info updated.");

        customerRepository.save(customer);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

As requested from others, I have added my service and controller classes as well. Maybe I am doing something wrong in here too.

Comment: `address` != `addresses` in your request. For the response, there is no `getAddresses` to return the address to the client.

Comment: You should show the code that corresponds to your ```get``` and ```post``` api

Comment: Done! I have added the service and controller classes.

Comment: 1. Check the database to see if the address data is inserted.  2. Try: @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER).

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS!! THANK YOU! @zysaaa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example data that you posted would work for a ManyToOne or a OneToOne relationship, but for the code that you posted, you would need something like this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"first_name": "Leon",
"last_name": "Hunter",
"addresses": [{
"street_number": "902",
"street_name": "Walker Road",
"city": "Clearfield",
"state": "Pennsylvania",
"zip": "16830"
}]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I changed it to a OneToOne, but I am still getting the same result.

Comment: @noobtovet OK. My guess is that you would need a getter and a setter for the address(es)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a one-to-one relationship for the address, this way all data for individual clients will be kept separate.

For example, if you have mum, dad and kid all linked to one address and the kid moves out, you might change their address and change the address for the parents which is unwanted behavior.

As for the Address not showing, what code are you using to retrieve the data?
I suspect because it isn't a primitive value(string) you may need to add a method to combine all the address data into a single string

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the prompt response! I am using postman to test all my methods. I hope that answers your question. If not, please feel free to clarify! Thanks.